# Multiplication of 1-forms

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, differential-forms

I decided to learn differential geometry by myself, and I am confused with the definition of the multiplication of 1-forms. According to the book that I am currently reading [1], given two 1-forms $\omega$ and $\nu$ on $T\mathbb{R}^2$, and vectors $V_1,V_2\in\mathbb{R}^2$, the operation
$$ \omega\wedge\nu(V_1,V_2)=\begin{vmatrix}\omega(V_1)&\nu(V_1)\\
\omega(V_2)&\nu(V_2)\end{vmatrix}$$
defines the *multiplication* of the 1-forms $\omega$ and $\nu$.

In Exercise 3.14 of [1] the author states

> Show that, for any 1-forms $\omega$ and $\nu$ on $T\mathbb{R}^3$, there exists constants $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ such that
> $$ \omega\wedge\nu=c_1 dx\wedge dy+c_2 dx\wedge dz + c_3 dy\wedge dz .$$

Why is this true?

[1] D. Bachman "A geometric approach to differential forms", Birkhauser, 2nd ed. 2012.

Comment: I am looking at the book right now, and it looks like the definition you gave for $\omega \wedge \nu$ is valid for any $\Bbb{R}^n$, not just when $n=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\omega = a dx + b dy + c dz$ and $\nu = p dx + q dy + r dz$. Then just compute using the determinant formula you gave:

$$ \begin {align*}
\omega \wedge \nu (V,W) &= \left| \begin{array}{cc} \omega(V) & \nu(V) \\ \omega(W) & \nu(W) \end{array} \right| \\
&= \left| \begin{array}{cc} av_1+bv_2+cv_3 & pv_1+qv_2+rv_3 \\ aw_1+bw_2+cw_3 & pw_1+qw_2+rw_3 \end{array} \right| \\ 
&= (av_1+b_2+cv_3)(pw_1+qw_2+rw_3) - (pv_1+qv_2+rv_3)(aw_1+bw_2+cw_3)
\end {align*} $$

After you multiply it out, some terms cancel, and what's left factors as:

$$ (aq-bp)(v_1w_2-v_2w_1) + (ar-cp)(v_1w_3-v_3w_1) + (br-cq)(v_2w_3-v_3w_2) $$

Notice that $v_1w_2-v_2w_1 = dx \wedge dy(V,W)$, and similarly $v_1w_3-v_3w_1 = dx \wedge dz(V,W)$ and $v_2w_3-v_3w_2 = dy \wedge dz(V,W)$.